# Angular 6 MVC project capture ActionResult in service

Tags: c#, json, angular, model-view-controller, actionresult

In an Angular 6 C#/MVC project, I am using ClosedXML nuget package to export data to excel. I have tried this by directly calling ExportToExcel method by setting it as action method in RouteCofing.cs **action = "ExportToExcel",** and it works fine and produces xlsx file, but in Angular project I am not sure how to retrieve control back to service class. Rest of the methods in controller return Task back, however this method returns ActionResult and I not sure how to get results back in service class. Please see the attached image for error.

Here is the code:

```
[![public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
        {
              //var sheetNames = new List<string>() { "sheetName1", "sheetName2" };
              var sheetNames = new List<string>() { "sheetName1" };


            string fileName = "SubmissionForm_" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
            GenerateBook gb = new GenerateBook();
            DataSet ds = gb.GetDSExportToExcel(); //gb.GetDataSetExportToExcel();

            XLWorkbook wbook = new XLWorkbook();

            for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables.Count; k++)
            {
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables\[k\];
                IXLWorksheet Sheet = wbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetNames\[k\]);
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Sheet.Cell(1, (i + 1)).Value = dt.Columns\[i\].ColumnName;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Sheet.Cell((i + 2), (j + 1)).Value = dt.Rows\[i\]\[j\].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            Stream spreadsheetStream = new MemoryStream();
            wbook.SaveAs(spreadsheetStream);
            spreadsheetStream.Position = 0;

            return new FileStreamResult(spreadsheetStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = fileName };

        }\[!\[enter image description here\]\[1\]\]\[1\]
    enter code here][1]][1]
```

[image]

call from service class:

private getExportExcelUrl = this.urlStr + '/Home/ExportToExcel';
public SetExport(data: any) {

```
    return this.http.post(this.getExportExcelUrl, null).subscribe((data: any) => { });
        //.pipe(map(res => <any[]>res))
        //.pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the response type to binary on your request?

Comment: modified post and added call from service class. And no, not setting response type to binary

Comment: The reason I ask is because the error you showed is indicating that it is trying to parse the response as JSON.

Comment: right. I don't know how to parse. That is the method I am using for rest of the database calls

Answer (score 0):

return File(memory, GetMimeType(file), filename);

You will have to return a memory stream (represented as "memory" below), then mimeType and fileName.

```
  private string GetMimeType(string file)
  {
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file).ToLowerInvariant();
    switch (extension)
    {
      case ".txt": return "text/plain";
      case ".pdf": return "application/pdf";
      case ".doc": return "application/vnd.ms-word";
      case ".docx": return "application/vnd.ms-word";
      case ".xls": return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
      case ".png": return "image/png";
      case ".jpg": return "image/jpeg";
      case ".jpeg": return "image/jpeg";
      case ".gif": return "image/gif";
      case ".csv": return "text/csv";
      default: return "";
    }
  }
```

From your API method:

```
      spreadsheetStream.Position = 0;
      return File(spreadsheetStream, GetMimeType(fileName), filename);
```

Refer [this blog](https://expertcodeblog.wordpress.com/2018/08/13/asp-net-core-angular-how-to-download-file-from-api-controller/) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Manoj, the swich case does not have case ".xlsx" so it touches default and then threw error System.ArgumentException: 'Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentType'

Comment: spreadsheetStream.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(spreadsheetStream, GetMimeType(fileName)) { FileDownloadName = fileName };  - return from api method I changed to this

Comment: @SilverFish - Did you try changing to xls to xlsx and then checked if it works ?

Comment: Still getting same parsing error. By the way, I know the method ExportToExcel does work. Isn't there a way not to capture return in service?

Answer (score 0):

On your post, pass in the parameter option for `responseType` of `arrayBuffer` or `blob`. Example:

```
this.http.get(this.getExportExcelUrl, { responseType: 'blob' })
```

EDIT: I changed the client request to GET. I'm not sure how your controllers are routing the requests. I usually map my own using Route attributes.

Comment: alan, this is not even touching the ExportToExcel in controller- nothing happens. I will need to pass it parameters to controller eventually

Comment: return this.http.post(this.getExportExcelUrl, null).subscribe((responseType: 'arraybuffer') => { }); this is the only call to controller that works, but produces the same parse error

Comment: The example code is only partial. You have to plug that in to your `subscribe` otherwise it will not get triggered.